# How do I use regex properly? Why isn't this working?

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```
string regex = "<Name[.\\s]*>[.]*s[.]*</Name>";
string source = "<Name xmlns=\"http://xml.web.asdf.com\">Session</Name>";


bool hit = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(
                                source,
                                regex,
                                System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                            );
```

Why is `hit` false? I'm trying to find any `Name` XML field that has an `'s'` in the name. I don't understand what could be wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Dude, are you trying to parse XML/XHTML with Regex? Were you aware of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 Please do something before the `<center>` crashes.

Comment: you should probably read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: See cthulu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Im not trying to parse HTML, the 'source' is a class Serialized.  I think I can handle regex with a serialized class, no?

Comment: @Tizz - When dealing with XML you use an XML parser and the provided API for querying the document. Regex adds needless complexity to a simple problem.

Comment: If it's serialized, why not just deserialize it?

Comment: Parsing XML with RegEx is like truck racing, it works but it's not meant to be used that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.` in a character class, where it means literally `.`, I think you mean to use in the sense of any character - so `.*` rather than `[.]*`

```
string regex = "<Name(.|\\s)*>.*s.*</Name>";
```

Answer (score 2):

With XPath, this could be as easy as `/Name[contains(.,'s')]`